# Custom nav with slick slider going out of sync with carousel slides

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm using [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to create a product carousel.

This example shows 4 products in the carousel. As you skip through the slides the nav above the products matches up: [Example](http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/single-use-laryngoscopes/)

This example shows 2 products. It's cloning the slides to make sure there's always 3 on the screen. The problem with this is that the nav above the products goes out of sync when you skip through: [Example](http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/nasopharyngeal-airways/). Essentially when you're on the cloned slides, when it skips through to the original slides the nav goes back into sync.

How can I get it to match up?

Here's my full code:

```
    // Category gallery

    // Set preferred slidesToShow
    var slidesToShow = 3; // always 3

    // Clone the slides.
    var $slides = $('.category-gallery .slide');
    if ($slides.length < slidesToShow + 1) {
        var $slide;
        $slides.each( function(){
            $slide = $(this).clone(true)
                .insertAfter( $slide || $slides.last() )
                .addClass('slick-cloned-2')
                .attr('id', '');
        });
    }

    $('.category-gallery').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: false,
        pauseOnHover:false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        centerMode:true,
        arrows: true,
    });

    $('a.category-nav[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
        $('.category-gallery').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
    });

    $('a.category-nav[data-slide="1"]').addClass("highlighted-cat-nav");
    $('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        $('a.category-nav').removeClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
      $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
    });
```

The problem seems to be on this line:

```
      $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
```

Comment: How about `(currentSlide%2 + 1)`, seems like you have this problem when you just have 2 products.

Comment: Hi Rob. Why did you disable the `var i = currentSlide >= slidesToShow ? currentSlide - slidesToShow : currentSlide;`? That should work, like it did. Try to enable it back and change `(currentSlide + 1)` to `i`.

Comment: @SallyCJ I found some issues with it. When there's more than 3 in the slider it breaks the nav, it only goes to the 3rd product then back to the start (not to the 4th item in the nav) and when there's less than 3 products it doesn't center them. (have a look at the two links now to see the problems). It's so close though.

Comment: "It's cloning the slides to make sure there's always 3 on the screen" - you know slick has a built in option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to my comment, the problem is probably because the `data-slide` is 1-based, but the `currentSlide` is 0-based.

Secondly, we should probably just use `currentSlide + 1` when the manual slides cloning is *not* necessary.

So change the following:

```
// Clone the slides.
var $slides = $('.category-gallery .slide');
if ($slides.length < slidesToShow + 1) {
```

to this one:

```
// Clone the slides.
var $slides = $('.category-gallery .slide'),
    clone_slides = ($slides.length <= slidesToShow),
    slides_count = Math.min($slides.length, slidesToShow);

if (clone_slides) {
```

Then try this:

```
$('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var i = clone_slides ?
        (currentSlide >= slides_count ? currentSlide - slides_count : currentSlide) + 1 :
        currentSlide + 1;
    $('a.category-nav').removeClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
  $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + i + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
});
```

---

**PS:** Make sure to use *unique variable names* — i.e. `slidesToShow`, `clone_slides`, `slides_count`, `slidesToShow2`, `clone_slides2`, `slides_count2`, etc. Then make sure to use the *proper names* in the code you copied which uses those variables.

Comment: `clone_slides = ($slides.length < slidesToShow + 1)` works as well.. but I chose to use `clone_slides = ($slides.length <= slidesToShow)`.

Comment: Hi Sally, that worked perfectly, thanks for the help again... comprehensive as usual. Tested it on carousels with 2, 3, 4+ slides and it worked on all of them.

Comment: Hi Rob, you're very welcome, and I'm glad it worked well. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this if statement. Probably it will need some extra tweaking.

```
$('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if(currentSlide >= $slides.length) { // added this if
    currentSlide -= $slides.length
  }

  $('a.category-nav').removeClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
  $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
});
```